# What do these arrows mean in Eclipse Kepler?

Tags: java, eclipse

I've got these arrows on a number of files in a Dynamic Web project in Eclipse Kepler. What do they mean?

[image]

There are also on a number of files in my WebContent directory:

[image]

Comment: If you are using a source control system (such as Git, SVN or CVS) the '>' means you have changed the file since it was last checked in.

Comment: It is the change in repository.

Comment: As @greg-449 noted, this means that your project is under a version control system and this file has been modified but is not commited.

Comment: That would make sense as just yesterday I made the project a git repository. Thank you.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you are using a source control system (such as Git, SVN or CVS) the '>' means you have changed the file since it was last checked in.

Most source control systems let you configure this character and other label options. For example with SVN it is in Preferences > Team > SVN > Label Decorations.

Newer versions of Eclipse call the preference "Version Control (Team)" rather than just "Team".